# What are typical entrance skin dose rates in radiography?

Tags: radiation, radiology, x-rays, ct-scans

I am designing a radiation dosimeter, and I am trying to work out if it can **detect the radiation rate/dose used in radiography** procedures (with **dosimeter placed on the patients body**). I want to start by mapping the min-max doses, and min-max dose rates for X-ray and CT scans.

I want to find, for different radiography procedures (X-ray, CT scan), what is the:

- entrance skin dose rate
- max entrance skin dose in a single point.

I am finding sources that have the effective dose [mSv] [Radiation Dose in X-Ray and CT Exams](https://www.radiologyinfo.org/en/info/safety-xray)

[image: Procedure Approximate effective radiation dose Comparable to natural background radiation for: Computed Tomography (CT)–Abdomen and Pelvis 7.7 mSv 2.6 years Computed Tomography (CT)–Abdomen and Pelvis, repeated with and without contrast material 15.4 mSv 5.1 years Computed Tomography (CT)–Colonography 6 mSv 2 years Intravenous Urography (IVU) 3 mSv 1 year Barium Enema (Lower GI X-ray) 6 mSv 2 years Upper GI Study with Barium 6 mSv 2 years]

However, I cannot find sources in absorbed dose/absorbed dose rate in simple gray units, or with an easy conversion.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. Two issues spring to mind with this question. What benefit to the profession do you suppose this information would provide? Plus, wouldn't placing an object like this in the path of the x-ray interfere with the image output?

Comment: Hi @ChrisRogers, haven't studied very attentively the applications, i am before mapping the dose/energies to see what is possible.  i) dose tracking could be used to validate the correct dose is given to patient (for different reasons there could be less/more dose on the body), to reduce negative effects given from overexposure. In the case of radiotherapy to center the beam ii) The dosimeters we make are very thing, with most radiation passing trough, they don't really add anything to the overall mass of a person. Obviously though thing dosimeter = less sensitive as it stops less radiation.

Comment: @ChrisRogers do you know of any source where I can find the correct doses? I understand why they use effective dose since it is more useful for patients, but not very useful in my case.

Comment: I doubt you're going to find this information in medical literature. Medicine doesn't care about details like this; it cares about effective dose. This is more of an engineering problem. I think you're going to find the information in radiological engineering sources, not medical.